# superclass vs utility class for common code

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, refactoring, utility-method

I have the same method in 2 classes that copy fields from one object to  builders. I want to refactor it but I do not know if I should create a static method in an utility class or abstract it to a superclass.

The classes that shares this code are Beans and part of a multithreading app.

The method would be like:

```
protected static void copyPartyGroup(Message.Builder msgBuilder, 
    final PartyGroup partyIDsGroup, Party.Builder rartyBuilder) {

    rartyBuilder.setPartyID(partyIDsGroup.getId())
    ....

    msgBuilder.setID(partyIDsGroup.getId())

    ....

}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use a trait in java 8, It's an interface with default methods

see : https://opencredo.com/traits-java-8-default-methods/

or : https://dzone.com/articles/using-traits-in-java-8

If your two classes not share a same parent structure, don't use a super abstract class, if the only reason to create this super class is to share your method  `copyPartyGroup` is not a good practice.

see : Liskov substitution principle

[image]

If you want to respect the Single Responsability Principle:

I think you have to create a service class. 
In your case, maybe a threadsafe singleton  with syncronized methods for `rartyBuilder.setPartyID` and  `msgBuilder.setID`. (see [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom))

[image]

Comment: hi, your images have dead. Would you mind to update them?

Answer (score 1):

If you can extract a static method, then it is better to just do that.

Using inheritance to share code couples your code and makes it really hard to untangle later.